# Google maps place text search api return random result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi all I am working on project in which I am using Google Maps JavaScript API for text search. I have passed the following parameters in the request. (Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/simar5358/87gt5vys/5/ )

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '8000',
type: "Food",
query: 'Indian Food'
};
```

The response i get from google api can be seen in the console of fiddle provided above.

My question here is, i am getting all random places in reults with names like : Bombay Bar and Grill, Kaveri Madras Cuisine, Shalimar Restaurant etc. 
Whereas i have only searched for places with name "Indian Food" in the request.

Can someone please explain if there is something i am doing wrong?
Also if someone could explain how google is returning these results that would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355256/getting-relevant-rather-then-pseudo-random-results-with-google-maps-places-api

Comment: thanks for the response. But i am already using textSearch function of google api (as shown in the fiddle), and it still does not returns me exact match places to my query. Rather it returns me results with random places which do not even have the words i put in query text.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Facing the same problem here. Thanks

Comment: I never did figure out what was causing this. I just added my own pattern match to confirm and filter out the results that do not have the string I was looking for.